# GWT SuperDevMode ang Google App Engine (GAE) update issue

Tags: java, google-app-engine, gwt

When using SuperDevMode for a GWT application hosted in Google App Engine (GAE), changes in code when app is (re)compiled through `Dev Mode On` in the browser does not work unless both SuperDevMode server is turned off as well as the App Engine devserver running is also turned off and started again.

I think this is a bit of an issue, as compared to running in the "old" Dev Server which requires browser plugin, where changes are updated upon browser refresh. How to make SuperDevMode work with Google App Engine?